# How to avoid scrolling to the top of the page while refering '< a href = #id'>Click</a>?

Tags: html, css

Here is the example:

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_scrollspy.asp

1) Scroll down to Scrollspy Vertical Menu

2) Click any of the section

3) You will notice that all contents scroll to the top of the page because of href tag.

How to avoid that from begin scroll to top of the page ? But I still need href's action.

Before clicking anchor tag which refer href="#section2":

[image]

After clicking section 2:

[image]

Comment: This is not happening on the "real" example in http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_scrollspy&stacked=h

Comment: Can u please see the image ?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue on Firefox, but I can on Chrome. You could try adding a click event handler on the links and put `event.preventDefault()` in it.

Comment: sorry. event.preventDefault() completely  prevents anchor tag reference. But I want to keep it alive so only I can refer it to some div.

Comment: Yes. you are right. This issue is only on chrome. May I know Why ?